# How can i get a the value from a variable, which has an another scope in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to desing the color of a button depending on one input value.

Herefore i am making if clauses to change the const `mycolor` depending of the input value `state1`

```
if(state1=== "good") {const mycolor="green"}
if(state1 === "medium") { const mycolor="yellow"}
if(state1 === "functional") {const mycolor="red"}

console.log(mycolor)
```

mycolor is not defined, because it is in the scope of the if statement.
How can i get access to it?

Comment: Don't declare the variable inside the `if` scope? `let mycolor = null; if (state1 === "good") { mycolor = "green"; }...`

Comment: `let mycolor="defaultColor";
if(state1=== "good") {mycolor="green"}
if(state1 === "medium") { mycolor="yellow"}
if(state1 === "functional") { mycolor="red"}

console.log(mycolor)`

Comment: Define it outside, without const. You are done

Comment: Use switch operator for cases like this instead of millions of ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Define `mycolor` outside of the scope.

```js
let mycolor = ''

if (state1 === 'good') 
  mycolor = 'green'
if (state1 === 'medium')
  mycolor = 'yellow'
if (state1 === 'functional')
  mycolor = 'red'

console.log(mycolor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside of the if statement (using let) and then just mutate it depending on the state.

Comment: You can also use the ternary operator to declare your color variable depending on the state1 variable.

const mycolor = state1 === "good" ? "green" : state1 === "medium" ? "yellow" : "red"